# Problem with CSS breakpoints selectors override with SASS

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I have a `_display.scss` partial.

It contains `@mixin` and *classes* related to display CSS property.

***_display.scss***

```
@mixin d-block{
    display: block;
}

@mixin d-none{
    display: none;
}

.d-block{
    @include d-block();
}

.d-none{
    @include d-none();
}
```

I developer a `@mixin` **generate-responsive-content** that take the `@content` of a class and generate a different *@media query* for each breakpoint.

In this way:

```
.d-block{
    @include generate-responsive-content() {
        @include d-block();
    }
}

.d-none{
    @include generate-responsive-content() {
        @include d-none();
     }
}

// Generate all breakpoints from content
@mixin generate-responsive-content() {

  // Responsive styles
  // Loop over each size
  @each $breakName, $width in $breakpoints {

    // Check breakpoint
    @if ($breakName != "") {
      $breakName: '-' + $breakName;

      @media (min-width: $width) {
        &#{$breakName} {
          @content
        }
      }

    } @else {
      @content;
    }

  }
}
```

eg. generated classes: `.d-block`, `.d-block-xs`, `.d-block-sm`...

But in this way, I cannot override the classes of `.d-none` with the classes of `.d-block` for each breakpoint because they have been generated before and are overwritten by those of `.d-none`.

I also have a class with the same name but without breakpoint variant, like `d-none-lg`, `d-block-lg`, these overwrite all others.

Check this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/alessandroinfo/pen/vYOLNPP). Here `d-none` variants overwrite every class of `d-block`.

How I can solve that?

Comment: _I cannot override the classes of .d-none with the classes of .d-block_ I'm not sure what this means. Can you post more of your output?

Comment: Can you please post what `generate-responsive-content()` mixin does?

Comment: @disinfor If I put a `d-none` class and `d-block-md`, the class `d-block-md` (and also other d-block-** classes) is always overwritten by `d-none` because is the last written by the mixin.

Comment: I still don't understand what is getting overwritten - as the mixin shouldn't be overwriting anything. Add the `$breakName`, and `$breakpoints` variables so we can run what you have.

Comment: @disinfor I mean the classes generated by the mixin `generate-responsive-content` are overwritten.

Comment: @RhythmRuparelia added.

Comment: @Ale_info again, please add the other information to actually run your mixin. I'm not sure why your classes would be overwritten, since the mixin would only be run with the content that is supplied.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer to include `max-width` breakpoint.

```
.see{outline:1px solid black;padding:1em;}
// BREAKPOINT
$breakpoints: (
  "xs": 575px,
  "sm": 576px,
  "md": 768px,
  "lg": 992px,
  "xl": 1200px
);

@mixin d-block() {
  display: block;
}

@mixin d-none() {
  display: none;
}

.d-block{
    @include d-block();
}

.d-none{
    @include d-none();
}

// Generate all breakpoints from content
@mixin generate-responsive-content() {

  // Responsive styles
  // Loop over each size
  @each $breakName, $width in $breakpoints {

    // Check breakpoint
    @if ($breakName == 'xs' ) {
      $breakName: '-' + $breakName;

      @media (max-width: $width) {
        &#{$breakName} {
          @content
        }
      }
    }
    @else if ($breakName != 'xs' ) {
      $breakName: '-' + $breakName;

      @media (min-width: $width) {
        &#{$breakName} {
          @content
        }
      }

    } @else {
      @content;
    }

  }
}

.d-block{
    @include generate-responsive-content() {
        @include d-block();
    }
}

.d-none{
    @include generate-responsive-content() {
        @include d-none();
     }
}
```

This is what is output:

```
.see {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
}

.d-block {
   display: block;
}


.d-none {
   display: none;
 }

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .d-block-xs {
    display: block;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .d-block-sm {
    display: block;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .d-block-md {
    display: block;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .d-block-lg {
    display: block;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .d-block-xl {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .d-none-xs {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .d-none-sm {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .d-none-md {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .d-none-lg {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .d-none-xl {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

UPDATED CODEPEN: Here's the OPs codepen, with this update:
https://codepen.io/chrislafrombois/pen/JjdGKGJ

Here is the code from the pen:

```css
.see {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
}

.d-block {
  display: block;
}

.d-none {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .d-block-xs {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .d-block-sm {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .d-block-md {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .d-block-lg {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .d-block-xl {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .d-none-xs {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .d-none-sm {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .d-none-md {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .d-none-lg {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .d-none-xl {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="see">
  <span>I CANNOT SEE ANYTHING BECAUSE d-none OVERWRITE EVERYTHING</span>
  <div class="d-none d-none-xs d-block-sm d-block-md d-block-lg">
    CHECK CSS STYLE D-BLOCK-LG OVERWRITE EVERITHING
  </div>
</div>
```

Per our discussion, you should not try and put the default `d-none` and `d-block` into this mixin. Because of how the code will output, you should just separate that concern and place the defaults before the media query blocks.

Comment: But if i want to put `.d-none-md` for **md** and `.d-block-xs` for **xs** i cannot, because will always be overwritten.

Comment: So, this isn't a SCSS issue, it's an HTML classes issue. If you have an element like this `<div class="d-block-xs d-none-md"></div>` - it will display as block until a viewport width of `992px`. I'm still not sure of what the actual issue is.

Comment: Take a look at my CodePen.

Comment: Ah, you need to change up your mixin a little bit to include `max-width` for the smallest breakpoint then. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Here's your codepen with this code: https://codepen.io/chrislafrombois/pen/MWwKKbO

Comment: @Ale_info yeah, but you didn't update it with the code I provided. If you look at the codepen I supplied based on your needs, it adds the `(max-width)` media query for the smallest screen (which is the issue you are running into).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207781/discussion-between-ale-info-and-disinfor).

Answer (score 0):

I have created a quick demo for you - https://codepen.io/rhythm19/pen/OJVMyLa and its working as expected. I think you just need to swap the order. Generate `d-none` classes first and then `d-block` classes.

```
.d-none{
    @include generate-responsive-content() {
        @include d-none();
     }
}

.d-block{
    @include generate-responsive-content() {
        @include d-block();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a solution because if a want `d-none` not overwritten by `d-block`? I have a solution and is to generate the classes with same breakpoint like: `.d-block-xs{}`, `.d-none-xs{}`, `.d-block-sm{}`, `.d-none-sm{}`, but i don't know how.

Comment: @Ale_info Did you check the codepen link. I have created 4 cases and they are working as expected. Can you let me know a scenario when it will not work?